# Outlook 365 and Gmail IMAP: deleted email remains in GMail server "All Mail" folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Emails deleted in Outlook 365 are still present in GMail "All Mail" folder but not in "Bin" folder.

How to move those deleted emails to GMail "Bin" in Outlook 365?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ever come across this problem, you need to properly configure Gmail and Outlook to get this working as you expect.

## GMail

Goto [GMAIL settings/Forwarding and POP/IMAP](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/fwdandpop)

You must set **Auto-Expunge** to **off**, then select **Move the message to Bin**.

[image]

## Outlook

If you don't have **[Gmail]/Bin** in your outlook, then you must add it by subscribing to the folder:

- Right click your Gmail (above GMail/Inbox) in Outlook.
- Select **IMAP Folders**.
- Select **Query**.
- Click **[Gmail]/Bin** when it shows up.
- Click **Subscribe**.
- Click **OK**.

[image]